# Best EC2 instance type for an nginx rewrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This maybe should be elsewhere, but I don't know where.

I'm making an instance which just does rewriting and forwards to another server.

What's the best instance type for that (m*, i*, etc) - many incoming connections, potentially big loads passing through on the way back, but very little compute power needed on this instance itself?

Comment: One nice thing about EC2 is that you can pretty much change the instance type whenever you want by simply shutting down the instance, changing the settings for the instance, then rebooting it.  So if you do determine that whatever you chose is too over/under powered you can always change it at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

"what server should I use" is (almost) always answered with "test it and see".

To just do lightweight redirects, you can probably get away with something very small. Start with a t2.small and use [Apache Bench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench) to see what volume it can handle. Simple work with nginx supports crazy-high threads per second- in fact, high enough that it'll be hard for `ab` to really test it. (oh yeah, run `ab` on a much larger server, or use something like [bees with machine guns](https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns) to scale it out; otherwise you are testing the throughput of the testing machine)

In reality you probably want to run this through an ELB and have more than one server behind it for stability. For instance, you might run three t2.smalls rather than one m3.medium.